# Wordpress add author name at the beginning of the Excerpt

Tags: php, wordpress

Is there a way to add to the beginning of the excerpt in wordpress? I'm try to add in the author's name like this, so that it's all within the same block of text:

```
<strong>(<?php echo get_the_author(); ?>) --</strong> Excerpt text....
```

It would look like:

**(AuthorName) --** Excerpt Text.....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$custom_excerpt = '<strong>('.get_the_author() .') ---</strong>'.get_the_excerpt();
echo $custom_excerpt ;
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this function: the_author();

for your refence: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/the_author

Comment: I'm not having any trouble getting the author to display, I need to add the_author(); or get_the_author(); into the_excerpt(); so that it displays before the excerpt text and within the fist line of text in the excerpt. Thanks though.